Error Integrating OpenFeign with Spring Boot for FHIR API
I am trying to establish a connection between two microservices using OpenFeign in a Spring Boot project to access a FHIR API. However, I am encountering a DecodeException when attempting to send a QuestionnaireResponse. Here is the code I am using:
fist microservice
@Create()
public MethodOutcome create(@ResourceParam QuestionnaireResponse questionnaire) {
    QuestionnaireResponse q = dao.create(questionnaire);
    MethodOutcome method = new MethodOutcome();
    method.setCreated(true);
    method.setResource(q);
    return method;
}

Second microservice:
OpenFeign:
@FeignClient(name = "AnamneseSystem")
public interface AnamneseProxy {

    @PostMapping(value = "/fhir/QuestionnaireResponse", consumes = "application/json")
    MethodOutcome createQuestionnaireResponse(@RequestBody String questionnaireJson);
}

Service:
  public MethodOutcome submitQuestionnaire(String questionnaireJson) {
        try {
            FhirContext ctx = FhirContext.forR5();
            IParser parser = ctx.newJsonParser();
            QuestionnaireResponse questionnaire = parser.parseResource(QuestionnaireResponse.class, questionnaireJson);
            String serializedQuestionnaire = parser.encodeResourceToString(questionnaire);
            System.out.println("Serialized QuestionnaireResponse: " + serializedQuestionnaire);


            MethodOutcome outcome = anamneseProxy.createQuestionnaireResponse(serializedQuestionnaire);

            return outcome;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new MethodOutcome().setCreated(false);
        }
    }

Controller:
    @PostMapping(value = "/questionnaire", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<MethodOutcome> createQuestionnaire(@RequestBody String questionnaireJson) {
        MethodOutcome outcome = anamneseService.submitQuestionnaire(questionnaireJson);
        if (outcome.getCreated()) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(outcome);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(outcome);
        }
    }

When I call the submitQuestionnaire method, I receive the following error message:
Feign.codec.DecodeException: HAPI-1716: Resource class[ca.uhn.fhir.rest.api.MethodOutcome] does not contain any valid HAPI-FHIR annotations
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.decode(AsyncResponseHandler.java:119)
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:87)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy152.createQuestionnaireResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.patientsystem.app.service.AnamneseService.submitQuestionnaire(AnamneseService.java:42)
    at com.example.patientsystem.app.service.AnamneseController.createQuestionnaire(AnamneseController.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: ca.uhn.fhir.context.ConfigurationException: HAPI-1716: Resource class[ca.uhn.fhir.rest.api.MethodOutcome] does not contain any valid HAPI-FHIR annotations
    at ca.uhn.fhir.context.ModelScanner.scan(ModelScanner.java:220)
    at ca.uhn.fhir.context.ModelScanner.init(ModelScanner.java:136)
    at ca.uhn.fhir.context.ModelScanner.<init>(ModelScanner.java:95)
    at ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext.scanResourceTypes(FhirContext.java:1019)
    at ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext.scanResourceType(FhirContext.java:1005)
    at ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext.getResourceDefinition(FhirContext.java:484)
    at ca.uhn.fhir.parser.BaseParser.parseResource(BaseParser.java:600)
    at com.example.patientsystem.app.config.FhirDecoder.decode(FhirDecoder.java:22)
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.decode(AsyncResponseHandler.java:115)```


That's not an error message from Spring Cloud.
